# Python Django, Stripe charge, APIConnectionError

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement the Stripe card payment on my site, I'm fairly new to their API, looked at their examples, I prefer to have separate fields for cardnumber, expirydate, and cvc, so I didn't use the card object. Followings are my codes:

Javascript: The following is the final button click event at the checkout.html page, where a token is generated and various values in the hidden input fields are set, before submitting to the charge.html page.

```
 $("#cardPayBtn").click(function() {
    var options = {
    };
    stripe.createToken(cardNumber, options).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('cardErrors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            //alert(errorElement);
        }
        else {
            $("#chargeAmount").val(parseInt($("#totalFee").val())*100);
            $("#chargeCurrency").val("gbp");
            $("#tokenSource").val(JSON.stringify(result.token));
            $("#cardPaymentForm").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

In the chargeView.py file, the post method is used to handle the form-post action from the checkout.html page, and create a charge as following;

```
def post(self, request):

    token = request.POST["tokenSource"]
    chargeAmount = request.POST['chargeAmount']
    chargeCurrency = request.POST['chargeCurrency']


    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=chargeAmount,
        currency=chargeCurrency,
        description='Example charge',
        source=json.loads(token),
    )

    return render(request, self.template)
```

I checked, there are values in amount, currency and source; however, the charge does not go through with following errors;

```
APIConnectionError at /photos/charge/
Unexpected error communicating with Stripe.  If this problem persists,
let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error: SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",))
```

After couple hours searching, I'm a bit clueless, any help or suggestion is appreciated, thanks !

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself, it is due to the outdated OpenSSL certification on the company, if your openSSL version is below 1.0.xx you are required to update it, I'm using MAC OS, so can be updated via Brew, then install a new version of Python and link the SSL to the new Python, all dependencies under the requirement.txt needs to be reinstalled.